# Serializing parent class fields using ServiceStack Redis/TextSerializer

Tags: serialization, redis, servicestack

I have two classes

```java
public class ClassOne {
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class ClassTwo : ClassOne {
}
```

When I send an instance of ClassTwo to Redis (using ServiceStack via its TypeSerializer) the superclass properties (e.g. Id) does not Serialize because it's on the parent class.

Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: Try adding `virtual` to the `Id` property.

Answer (score 0):

Only abstract classes, interfaces or late-bound objects emit the necessary __type info required for inheritance to work. So if you must use inheritance (which is a bad idea in DTOs) change ClassOne to abstract.